# What happens to a mutex held by a thread waiting on a condition variable

Tags: multithreading

For a program I'm writing, I will want to have a thread hold two mutexes simultaneously.  It will then wait on a condition variable, using one of those mutexes as the mutex associated to the condition variable.  What happens to the other mutex while it's waiting?  Is it still locked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pthread_cond_wait](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html)() only unlocks(and locks it again when it returns) the mutex you pass to it, not any other mutexes.

Answer (score 0):

It must be, otherwise conditional variables would be impossible to use.